# "Read" skipping last word on each line

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm getting some weird behaviour from a for loop that reads each line in a file and after each line, reads every word. Read skips the last word on each line. I think I may have to specify that both whitespace and newline are deliminator but I haven't found out how to do that. Here is the part of the script that matters:

```
  cat $i | while read line    
    do
        echo $line
        sleep 1
        #Process each word
        echo $line | while read -d ' '  word
        do
            echo $word
            sleep 1
        done
    done
```

Comment: Avoid unnecessary `cat`s: `while read line; do …; done < $i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you see [How to split one string into multiple strings separated by at least one space in bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469849/how-to-split-one-string-into-multiple-strings-in-bash-shell)? maybe you could just do:

```
for word in $line
do
    echo $word
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: That seems to work like a charm, guess I was too hung up on using read since I use it to read the file.

Comment: Not sure, but I think this will subject $line to the usual shell expansions, which might turn out to be more than you want.  You'll want to experiment with what happens with input lines containing double- and single-quotes and backticks (balanced and unbalanced), and dollar-signs (`$`). If this turns out to be a problem for you, you might consider the solution based around `fmt` which I suggest below.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of the `for` command is:

```
      for name [ [in [words ...] ] ; ] do commands; done
```

Expand words, and execute commands once for each member in the resultant list, with name bound to the current member.

```
cat $i | while read line    
do
    echo $line
    sleep 1
    #Process each word
    for word in $line
    do
        echo $word
        sleep 1
    done
done
```

Comment: That seems to work like a charm, guess I was too hung up on using read since I use it to read the file

Answer (score 0):

Try using the cut command instead of read -d

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to remember the line boundaries, the `fmt` command can be useful.  `fmt` reflows plain text on stdin into given maximum line length, and so if you give it a max line length of one, it ends up splitting each word of the input onto its own line.  For your problems, perhaps

```
cat $1 |
fmt -1 |
while read word
do
    # do something with $word
end
```

Note that you've lost all original line boundaries here, and you're dependent on `fmt`'s definition of what a word is.  If you really need the line boundaries for some reason, you could think about something like

```
cat $1 |
while read line
do
    # do something with $line
    echo "$line" | 
    fmt -1 |
    while read word
    do
        # do something with $word
    done
done
```