# search the output line and save in variable

Tags: shell, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

How to search word of the output of a shell script and save in other variable .

Below command will display the list of baselines in my view .

```
cmd :cleartool lsstream -fmt "%[found_bls]NXp\n" -view $VIEW_NAME
```

Output :

```
baseline:MHC_BUILDTREE1.0.1
baseline:JEPG_DUIF_CI
baseline:MOR_BuildTree_BLD_I.0.1
```

I need to search the line which contains `"MOR_BuildTree"` and that output line i have to save in one variable to execute the rest of the commands .
Can any one give the suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are asking, but to set a variable to the result of a command, you can use:

```
var=`command`
```

or you can pipe your command to some filter to reformat it as required.

```
command | some_filter | another filter
```

you can also combine the two:

```
var=`command | some_filter | another filter`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I just tested to get one baseline out of all the foundation baselines:

```
$ res=`cleartool lsstream -fmt "%[found_bls]CXp" -view $VIEW_NAME | tr -s " " "\\012" | grep $yourBaselineName| sed -e "s/.*://" -e "s/@.*//"`
```

(set `$yourBaselineName` to the appropriate name you want to extract)

The main difficulty comes from the fact an `lsstream -fmt "%[found_bls]CXp"`**will list all foundation baselines on the same output line** (so the output is only one line of baseline names, separated by comma).
You need to split the line into multiple ones first.
See "[How to split one string into multiple strings in bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1473853/6309)": that is the `tr -s " " "\\012"` part of the above command.

Then you need to remove what precede and follow the baseline name:

```
 baseline:aBaselineName@/vobs/YourPVob
```

The `sed` part of the above command can do that:

```
sed -e "s/.*://" -e "s/@.*//"
```

(two regular expressions remove everything before the '`:`' and after the '`@`')

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a simple piece shell scripting?

```
variable=$(cmd :cleartool lsstream -fmt "%[found_bls]NXp\n" -view $VIEW_NAME |
           sed -n '/MOR_Buildtree/s/^baseline://p')
```

The `-n` options means 'do not print by default'.  The command looks for your name, removes the leading `baseline:` and prints it.