# clearcase ucm baseline

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-ucm

Is there any way to get the composte baseline information from the current view in command line .

I am using the comand in my script. It's displaying the list of the commands which include composite and ovverride component baselines in my view .

cleartool lsstream -fmt "%[found_bls]NXp\n" -view $VIEW_NAME

I need only the composite baseline as output for my command.

Is there any command to findout the composite baseline in current view ? pls help .

Answer (score 0):

I guess your composite baselines are rootless components, so you can check the components and display only rootless. You can use `cleartool describe` for that.

Answer (score 0):

A [composite baseline](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/5134.html) can list its immediate dependencies, so as described in [this script](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21222139), you can attempt to list those for each baselines.
the one that does return an output (without error) is your composite baseline.

```
cleartool describe -fmt "%[depends_on]Np\n" {baseline selector}
```

However, building on my previous answer about "[search the output line and save in variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527870/search-the-output-line-and-save-in-variable/9529245#9529245)", what you can do is describe each baseline, asking for its dependencies, and grepping for the line which contains an arobase '`@`':
Only composite baselines will return fully qualified baseline names, with arobase in it, as opposed to a non-composite baseline, which will return... nothing)

```
cleartool lsstream -fmt "%[found_bls]CXp" -view $VIEW_NAME | tr -s " " "\012" | xargs cleartool descr -fmt "%n %[depends_on]Cp" | grep "@" | sed -e "s/ .*//"
```

For more visibility:

```
cleartool lsstream -fmt "%[found_bls]CXp" -view $VIEW_NAME \
| tr -s " " "\012" 
| xargs cleartool descr -fmt "%n %[depends_on]Cp" 
| grep "@" | sed -e "s/ .*//"
```