# rebasing a set of baselines

Tags: java, clearcase, cleartool

I want to rebase a set of baselines.Separating each baseline to be mentioned in the rebase command with a comma is one option and the other is to take each and every baseline separately and give the rebase -baseline [name of baseline] - complete command as many number of times as the there are number of baselines, both of which are time consuming.

Is there a way to rebase quickly with least effort?

Answer (score 0):

One [`cleartool rebase`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc%255Fref.doc/topics/ct_rebase.htm) command, with baselines separated by coma, is certainly quicker.

Note that you could [list all the latests baselines of a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8132683/6309) and get that list fairly quickly that way.

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%[latest_bls]CXp," stream:aStream@\aPVob
```

---

But if you don't want to list all baselines, you can:

- create a rootless component
- put all the other components as dependent of that new rootless component (through the GUI, or [you can do it in command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17318270/6309))

That will create a composite baseline, that you can use for rebasing another stream.
One baseline.
Multiple components rebased.

See also:

- "[What is composite baseline in UCM and when it will be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9613986/6309)".
- "[Best practices for using composite baselines in UCM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/5134.html)"
- "[composite baseline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9528328/6309)"