# create and recommend clearcase UCM baseline

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-automation

I am in need of a script(Batch) which is suppose to create a baseline and recommend it on all components. Please help if anybody have it. I am using following commands

```
cd M:/view_name
ct mkbl -all -full -ident -c "baseline comment" baseline_name stream_name@project_vob
ct chstream -recommend baseline_name@project_vob
```

with these commands it creates baseline_name in one component and `baseline_name.xxxx` on all other components. and recommends only one baseline(without `.xxxx` on end).

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior: with a composite baseline, only the one created on the rootless component gets recommended.
See "[What is composite baseline in UCM and when it will be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9613986/6309)".

If you right click on the stream and select "properties", on the tab "components", you can select that rootless component, and see the list of baselines created.

Select that last baseline, click on properties, and you will see that baseline actually includes all the others: by recommended one, you actually recommend all the other as well (they are included in that composite baseline).

You can also describe that baseline (the one without the `.xxxx`) to see its dependencies: see "[clearcase ucm baseline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9528328/6309)".

If that hadn't work (ie, if you don't see the other baselines included in it), then you might have to specify the dependencies manually on the `mkbl` step.
See "[Create composite baseline via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17318270/6309)".

Comment: Hi VonC,Thanks for information. Actually need to use this script to do everything automatically. means can't use GUI to change or recommend baseline at all. This scrip will be part of automated build process which is suppose to create baseline on stream and recommend it on all components.

Comment: @user3232823 that is why I linked to http://stackoverflow.com/a/17318270/6309: everything can be done in command-line