# Files getting removed on stream recommendation for a baseline

Tags: clearcase

Post delivering the changes a baseline is created after which when we recommend that baseline using the below command

> ct chstream -recommended  streamName

The following files got removed... could someone suggest how to avoid these files from being removed.

```
ct: Warning: Removing component "shared" from the stream's recommended baselines might prevent
streams from rebasing -recommended, since they might have changes in the dropped component.
ct: Warning: Removing component "lsba_build" from the stream's recommended baselines might prevent
streams from rebasing -recommended, since they might have changes in the dropped component.
ct: Warning: Removing component "lsba_pkgtool" from the stream's recommended baselines might prevent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That message should occurs when there is a composite component present in the stream.

Check "right-click on the stream" + "Edit baseline dependencies": if you see a component with a '+' (which can be unfolded), then you have a composite component (for defining **[composite baseline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9613986/6309)**)

Its list of dependent components must match the list of the components present on the stream, or any "recommended baseline" will drop the components of the streams which are not listed in the dependencies of that "composite component".

Comment: Thanks VonC for your explanation.

Will the above steps applicable/same in unix environment too cause I am not able to edit baseline dependencies in unix environment.

Comment: @yanivx yes, you can list baselines dependencies using `cleartool`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9528328/6309

Comment: @yanivx and you can edit (make a new one) baseline dependencies with cleartool too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17318270/6309 (after https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbl.htm)