# how to parse a string word by word in a shell script?

Tags: string, shell

I have a file containing strings like (the number of words in any string is random):

```
coge las hojas y las quemas todas en el fuego   k Wo x e l a s Wo x a s i l a s k We m a s t Wo D a s e n e l f w We G o 
la liga de paz se reunió para tratar el tema    l a l Wi G a d e p Wa T s e rr e w n j Wo p a r a t r a t Wa r e l t We m a
el bebé se mete el pie dentro de la boca    e l b e B We s e m We t e e l p j We d We n t r o d e l a b Wo k a
hoy en día el pollo es un plato común   Wo j e n d Wi a e l p Wo L o We s Wu n p l Wa t o k o m Wu n
```

I want to separate the string in words. For example, I would like to have from the first sentence 10 variables v1,v2,..v10 so that:

```
v1="coge"
v2="las"
...
v10="fuego"
```

Thank you in advance for your help!!!

Comment: you can use this [link][1] to find your answer :)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469849/how-to-split-one-string-into-multiple-strings-in-bash-shell

Comment: Should the 10th word on the 4th line be "Wo"? What is your criteria for determining when the "words" end?

Comment: the list of words is separated from the list of phones of the line by a tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that 3 or more spaces separates the words from the rest of the line:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    read -ra words <<< ${line%%   *}

    # do whatever you need with the words array here, for example
    for (( i=0; i<${#words[@]}; i++ )); do
        printf "%d - %s\n" $i "${words[i]}"
    done
done < filename
```

---

To use a tab character:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r words phones; do
    read -ra words_ary <<< $words

    # do whatever you need with the words array here, for example
    for (( i=0; i<${#words_ary[@]}; i++ )); do
        printf "%d - %s\n" $i "${words_ary[i]}"
    done
done < filename
```

Comment: thanks a lot! a tab separates the words from the rest of the line.

Comment: and I would like to take only the words before the list of phones. actually I want to get rid of the list of phones in each line.