# Retrieve only the word not the entire line

Tags: unix

> is.at.BigData:It is huge data this is very useful
>   is.in.was.SmallData:It is small data we should not lose the data
>   co.in.let.was.in.rem.MediumData:It is medium data Data is highly
>   confidential

I want the answer as:

```
BigData
SmallData
MediumData
```

There are many more lines in the file but I am providing you the sample text.

Comment: I want every word in different line

Comment: You can format your text like this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks You can also edit your own questions if you have things that you would like to add to it by clicking on "edit" See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work

Answer (score 0):

Your question was not very clear because it wasn't formatted, however:

```
paragraph='is.at.BigData:It is huge data this is very useful is.in.was.SmallData:It is small data we should not lose the data co.in.let.was.in.rem.MediumData:It is medium data Data is highly confidential'
```

And then something like:

```
echo $paragraph | grep -oe 'BigData\|SmallData\|MediumData'
```

Results in:

```
BigData
SmallData
MediumData
```

For every word that you want to search for you could put in a list. And loop over them.

Also see:

[How to split one string into multiple strings separated by at least one space in bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469849/how-to-split-one-string-into-multiple-strings-separated-by-at-least-one-space-in)

Comment: There were many lines in the file and it was not formatted.Only clue the word starts with (.)dot and contains the 'Data' in the word.