# How to split the string into two separate variables in shell

Tags: arrays, linux, string, bash, shell

I have an array of strings with the following numbers in it separated by a space.

```
S0 [
42 4677
S10 [
4719 1266
6020 3618
9667 8463
```

**I want to separate each value as an integer and put the in a separate array like 
array2 = [S0,42, 4677,S10, 4719, 1266, 6020, 3618, 9667, 843].**

What I have done is loop through the array like the solution given here

> [How to split one string into multiple strings separated by at least one space in bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469849/how-to-split-one-string-into-multiple-strings-separated-by-at-least-one-space-in)

for each element of the array but it doesn't seem to work.

```
for each in ${my_array[1]}
do
echo $each
done
```

always gives me the output `42 4677` as a single value.

> EDITED

```
for each in ${my_array[@]}
do
echo $each 
done    

declare -a array2
for each in ${my_array[@]}
do
    array2=$each
done 

echo ${array2[1]}

declare -p my_array
```

Now the first for loop works correctly but now when I assign the values of my_array to array2 in the second loop, only the last value of the last string is assigned to it i.e. `8463`.

The contents of `declare -p my_array` are 
`declare -a my_array='([0]="S0 [" [1]="42 4677" [2]="S10 [" [3]="4719 1266" [4]="6020 3618" [5]="9667 8463")'`

Comment: Show output of `declare -p my_array`

Comment: Try `for each in ${my_array[@]}`

Comment: @anubhava the output of the `my_array` is
`S0 [`
`42 4677`
`S10 [`
`4719 1266`
`6020 3618`
`9667 8463`

Comment: @MarkSetchell `${my_array[@]` works. But I get  a `array2: command not found` error when I use the same for loop to assign the values to the new array.

Comment: Please click `edit` under your original question and update it there rather than in comments which are hard to read. Please also be sure to answer @anubhava 's question and include whatever `array2` is.

Comment: @MarkSetchell  I have edited my original question. Kindly go through it again.

Comment: @anubhava I have answered your question in the original post.

Comment: Try `array2+="$each"`. Also, enclose in double quotes `"${my_array[@]}"`

Comment: @MarkSetchell  all the contents are now stored in a single string like 
`array2='([0]="S0 [42 4677S10 [4719 12666020 36189667 8463")'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
declare -a my_array='([0]="S0 [" [1]="42 4677" [2]="S10 [" [3]="4719 1266" [4]="6020 3618" [5]="9667 8463")'

array2=()

for i in ${my_array[@]}; do
   [[ $i == *[0-9]* ]] && array2+=($i)
done

# check content of array2
declare -p array2
declare -a array2=([0]="S0" [1]="42" [2]="4677" [3]="S10" [4]="4719" [5]="1266" [6]="6020" [7]="3618" [8]="9667" [9]="8463")
```