# How can I loop over comma-separated lists *inside* each line of a file?

Tags: bash

Need to write some status checker at bash-script:

Have file with strings like that:

```
domain.com; 111.111.111.111,222.222.222.222; /link/to/somefile.js,/link/to/somefile2.js
domain2.com; 122.122.111.111,211.211.222.222; /link/to/somefile2.js,/link/to/somefile3.js
```

Need to execute such commands at total:

```
curl -s -I -H 'Host: domain.com' http://111.111.111.111/link/to/somefile.js
curl -s -I -H 'Host: domain.com' http://222.222.222.222/link/to/somefile.js

curl -s -I -H 'Host: domain.com' http://111.111.111.111/link/to/somefile2.js
curl -s -I -H 'Host: domain.com' http://222.222.222.222/link/to/somefile2.js

curl -s -I -H 'Host: domain2.com' http://122.122.111.111/link/to/somefile2.js
curl -s -I -H 'Host: domain2.com' http://211.211.222.222/link/to/somefile2.js

curl -s -I -H 'Host: domain2.com' http://122.122.111.111/link/to/somefile3.js
curl -s -I -H 'Host: domain2.com' http://211.211.222.222/link/to/somefile3.js
```

The question is:

1. what tool do I need to use to have such result at total?
2. Maybe `xargs` with some arguments/flags can do that or gnu `parallel`?
3. Can you, please, show examples?

I can to separate lines and set result to different variables that's isn't problem at all:

```
domain=$(cut -d';' -f1 file| xargs -I N -d "," echo curl -H) \'N\'
ip=$(cut -d';' -f2 file| xargs -I N -d "," echo curl -H) \'N\'
and else
```

But question at other :)  : 
how after delimiting and separating strings to variables, I can execute curl with different variables at that case - the number of arguments for different variables will be different ?

The answer's that get Barmar doesn't cover task problem at all, cause it has greater than two list's. The problem is not at ignorance of bash, but of way I can resolve issue

Comment: Is it accurate that spaces can only appear concatenated to semicolons?

Comment: You can use a `while read` loop, after setting `IFS` so that it splits on `;` and space. Then split up the IP and pathname parts on space, and use a nested loop for that part.

Comment: [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) is a good place to start.

Comment: I believe this problem can be broken down into three separate technical challenges: Iterating over a file line-by-line (reading each column into a different variable); splitting a string on a delimiter into an array; and iterating over distinct arrays (the ones you split the IP and file fields into) in lockstep. We already have answered questions about how to do all of those things. If you're getting stuck somewhere else, please [edit] the question to show how you tried to apply those answers, and exactly which problem you still have.

Comment: I can to separate line with  and set result to different variables.  domain=(cut -d';' -f1 file| xargs -I N -d "," echo curl -H) \'N\', ip=(cut -d';' -f2 file| xargs -I N -d "," echo curl -H) \'N\'

Comment: But question at other :) how after delimiting and separating strings to variables I can execute curl with different variables at that case - the number of arguments for different variables will be different

Comment: The answer's that get Barmar doesn't cover task problem at all, cause it has greater than two list's

Comment: The code in your question doesn't appear to reflect any attempt to use or build on the answers to the linked duplicates, or the FAQ I linked earlier. (`xargs` isn't the right tool here; neither is `cut`, for that matter).

Comment: Yes, there are inner lists, but if you combine the linked answers you get what you need: Iterate over the lines, reading each of the columns into a variable; then split the columns that have inner lists into arrays; then iterate over the arrays. All the answers you need are there -- and if you showed code that indicated that you were trying to apply them and just ran into a problem in the attempt, you'd get a much friendlier reception than showing no effort or intent to listen to the advice you're given.

Comment: "xargs isn't the right tool here; neither is cut" because.. :) can you please explain your position? I resolve to problem's in one line if i add "while readline" around, there will leave one unresolved question: how to get curl works with this as you say "inner array's". The answer I get resolve work with two similar arrays but not even more

Comment: `cut` is expensive: Because it's not part of bash, every time you start it up, you're doing a fork and exec pair, plus all the FIFO overhead in the command substitution to capture its output. Bash has its own built-in string manipulation primitives -- see [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) -- and sticking to built-in functionality is way faster (pertinent if you're running in an inner loop over a lot of inputs).

Comment: Moreover, generating shell commands *as strings* has serious pitfalls -- see [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) if you try to evaluate them with `eval`, or [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) if you don't.

Comment: Thanks very much, sorry for my obvious questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- IMPORTANT: not /bin/sh

# print command instead of running it, so people can test their answers without real URLs
log_command() { printf '%q ' "$@"; printf '\n'; }

while IFS='; ' read -r domain addrs_str files_str; do
  IFS=, read -a addrs <<<"$addrs_str"
  IFS=, read -a files <<<"$files_str"
  for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    for addr in "${addrs[@]}"; do
      log_command curl -s -I -H "Host: $domain" "http://$addr/$file"
    done
  done
done
```

...emits as output (as the list of commands if it would run if the `log_command` prefix were removed):

```
curl -s -I -H Host:\ domain.com http://111.111.111.111//link/to/somefile.js 
curl -s -I -H Host:\ domain.com http://222.222.222.222//link/to/somefile.js 
curl -s -I -H Host:\ domain.com http://111.111.111.111//link/to/somefile2.js 
curl -s -I -H Host:\ domain.com http://222.222.222.222//link/to/somefile2.js 
curl -s -I -H Host:\ domain2.com http://122.122.111.111//link/to/somefile2.js 
curl -s -I -H Host:\ domain2.com http://211.211.222.222//link/to/somefile2.js 
curl -s -I -H Host:\ domain2.com http://122.122.111.111//link/to/somefile3.js 
curl -s -I -H Host:\ domain2.com http://211.211.222.222//link/to/somefile3.js
```

...as you can see at https://ideone.com/dTC8q8

---

Now how does this work?

- Step 1: Read each line into `domain`, `addrs_str` and `files_str`, split on semicolons and spaces.

  That's what's done by the line `IFS='; ' read -r domain addrs_str files_str`, which operates as described in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), and in [How to read variables from file, with multiple variables per line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906232/how-to-read-variables-from-file-with-multiple-variables-per-line)
- Step 2: For `addrs_str` and `files_str`, split them on commas into separate arrays. This is described in [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)
- Step 3: Iterate over those arrays, and call `curl` for each combination. If you wanted to call the first IP with only the first file, and the second IP with the second file, you could use [Iterate over two arrays simultaneously in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403498/iterate-over-two-arrays-simultaneously-in-bash); otherwise, it's a plain nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel it would look like this

```
doit() {
  domain="$1"
  ips="$2"
  paths="$3"
  parallel --dry-run -d ',' -q curl -s -I -H Host:\ "$domain" http://{1}/{2} ::: "$ips" ::: "$paths"
}
export -f doit
parallel --colsep ';' doit :::: input.file
```

Remove `--dry-run` when you are convinced it works.