# shell script by read a file and copy from source and destination

Tags: bash, loops, shell, scp

I want to create shell script by reading a file like below.

```
/shared36/Upload/IG/01014330122022010599/
/ftpvolume/FileUpload/01014330122022010599

/shared36/Upload/IG/01010504012023003961/
/ftpvolume/FileUpload/01010504012023003961

/shared36/Upload/IG/01011005012023007397/
/ftpvolume/FileUpload/01011005012023007397

/shared36/Upload/IG/01011403012023006138/
/ftpvolume/FileUpload/01011403012023006138

/shared36/Upload/IG/01013804012023001622/
/ftpvolume/FileUpload/01013804012023001622
```

I want to automate below task.

```
scp /ftpvolume/FileUpload/01014330122022010599/ABC.PDF   /shared36/Upload/IG/01014330122022010599/ABC.PDF

scp /ftpvolume/FileUpload/01010504012023003961/ABC.PDF   /shared36/Upload/IG/01010504012023003961/ABC.PDF
```

and so on....

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My script is below

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
dest=""
src=""
filename="test.txt"
while read -r line; do
    name="$line"
    if [[ $name =~ /shared && $name != "" ]]
    then
    echo "$name - Destination"
    fi

    if [[ $name =~ /ftpvolume && $name != "" ]]
    then
    echo "$name - Source"
    fi
    sleep 1
done< "$filename"
```

but I just want to put its source and destination into scp command

Comment: You don't need `$name != ""`, since an empty name won't match the regexp.

Comment: Thanks for reply Please suggest I want to read a file 1st 2 lines dst and src next 2 lines dst and src next 2 lines dst and src now I want to put these 2 lines into 

scp src dst
scp src dst

want to automate this

Comment: That's clear from the question. See the answer I posted below.

Comment: Hem why `scp` instead of simply `cp`?

Comment: You could maybe: `sed 'N;N;s/^\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n/cp "\2" "\1"/' <file | sh -v`

Comment: Basically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/how-to-merge-every-two-lines-into-one-from-the-command-line and then take it from there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906232/how-to-read-variables-from-file-with-multiple-variables-per-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set variables after each match. Then after you read the source, substitute them into the `scp` command.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
dest=""
src=""
filename="test.txt"
while read -r line; do
    name="$line"
    if [[ $name =~ /shared ]]
    then
        dest=$name
    elif [[ $name =~ /ftpvolume ]]
    then
        src=$name
        scp "$src/ABC.PDF" "$dest/ABC.PDF"
    fi
    sleep 1
done< "$filename"
```

Comment: That code is work for me I add some other code in existing code due to destination server is remote server and I want to check if directory is not exits in destination code will create directory first then scp command will run. please suggest.

Comment: I suggest you use `rsync` instead of `scp`. It will create directories as needed.

Answer (score 0):

That code is working for me and I change some code in this due to destination server is remote server and I want to check if directory is not exist in remote server then code will create directory first and then scp command will executed. Please suggest.

New Code :

```
    #!/bin/sh

dest=""
src=""
filename="test.txt"
while read -r line; do
    name="$line"
    if [[ $name =~ /shared ]]
    then
        dest=$name
    elif [[ $name =~ /ftpvolume ]]
    then
        src=$name
        echo "scp $src/ABC.PDF username@X.X.X.X:$dest/ABC.PDF"
        scp "$src/ABC.PDF" "username@X.X.X.X:$dest/ABC.PDF"
    fi
    sleep 1
done< "$filename"
```

Comment: The very first two characters on the first line need to be `#` and `!` in order for the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to work. You can't reliably use `#!/bin/sh` for scripts which use Bash syntax like `=~`; see also [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: And why do you copy the same value to three different variables? Just say `dest=$line` and then `scp "$line/ABC.PDF" "oracle@101.125.243.5:$dest/ABC.PDF"`