# separate elements of array in bash

Tags: bash

I have an array, on the attached screen.

I need to get all third components from this array.

Example (my existing array):

```
array1 = 
 ["SRV WW ZSTG HSM BlackDuck RW", "SRV WW ZSDB M204 BlackDuck RW", etc]
```

The result should be:

```
array2 = ["HSM", "M204"]
```

[image]

- I need to delete all empty elements from array

My code to work with it right now:

```
FILE="$1"

index=0
while read name; do
    get_group_names_from_file[$index]="$name"
    index=$(($index+1))
done < "${FILE}"

get_group_names_from_file=("${get_group_names_from_file[@]:3}")

for ((a=0; a < ${#get_group_names_from_file[*]}; a++))
do
    echo "${get_group_names_from_file[$a]}"
done
```

Comment: Arrays in `bash` don't take `,` to store its elements. What is your use-case here? How are you populating this array?

Comment: @Inian I updated ticket

Comment: What is your other requirement to delete empty elements from array? What does it mean?

Comment: @Inian on the screen, you can see last 2 elements is empty, there is no elements there, I need to delete these from my array.

Comment: It would be good if you can paste that content to the question above and explain it to your other useful information and show us the actual complete content of the array

Comment: @Inian ok, just help me with the first part, to get another array.

Comment: It is potentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1469849/5291015. If you add more details, then it could make a question unique

Comment: I don't understand your needs. Is it just to get the 3rd column of the file? If so, simply `cat file | cut -d ' ' -f 3` should be enough

Comment: @brunorey, yeap, I need third column, but where should I ad it in my code?

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Comment: `HSM` and `M204` are the 4th word, not the 3rd. Also, what do you really want to do? If you just want to print the 4th word of each line from a file then you don't need an array at all.

Comment: Don't use images. Posting an image of your source data is worse than [posting images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). I can't copy/paste that, and I'm not going to spend a lot of type typing it in so I can run tests to get you a solution.... Please replace the image with a 4-space indented block of the actual data sample.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the third column you can use the `cut` command (see [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html)):

```
FILE="$1"

for value in `cat $FILE | cut -d ' ' -f 3`
do
    echo "3rd column is $value"
done
```

Comment: [Don't read lines from a file with a for loop.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) Use while.

Comment: Don't need cat, cut can read files. To store in an array use: `readarray -t array < <(cut -f3 "$FILE")`

Answer (score 0):

I've set `ARRAY1` like this (there's no need for a `,` to seperate values in an array):

```
ARRAY1=("SRV WW ZSTG HSM BlackDuck RW" "SRV WW ZSDB M204 BlackDuck RW")
```

and extracted the third component of the array-values this way:

```
for (( i=0 ; i<$(echo ${#ARRAY1[*]}) ; i++ )) ; do ARRAY2+=($(echo ${ARRAY1[$i]} | cut -d ' ' -f3)); done
```

(If you want to have the 4th component, use `cut -d ' ' -f4` instead)

Checking values of `ARRAY2` via `printf '%s\n' "${ARRAY2[@]}"`

---

```
~$ ARRAY1=("SRV WW ZSTG HSM BlackDuck RW" "SRV WW ZSDB M204 BlackDuck RW")
~$ ARRAY2=() ; for (( i=0 ; i<$(echo ${#ARRAY1[*]}) ; i++ )) ; do ARRAY2+=($(echo ${ARRAY1[$i]} | cut -d ' ' -f3)); done
~$ printf '%s\n' "${ARRAY2[@]}"
~$ ZSTG
~$ ZSDB
```

Comment: I saw, that my request return string "SRV WW ZSTG HSM BlackDuck RW SRV WW ZSDB M204 BlackDuck RW", how can I transform it to array from the word SRV?

Comment: Seems like your array values mentioned initialy aren't seperated correctly. Make sure your values for `ARRAY1` are seperated like this:
`ARRAY=("Word1.1 Word1.2 Word1.3" "Word2.1 Word2.2 Word2.3")`. In your case specificly `ARRAY1=("SRV WW ZSTG HSM BlackDuck RW" "SRV WW ZSDB M204 BlackDuck RW")`

Comment: you are right, but it doesn't separate. they looks like ARRAY=("ValueA1 ValueA2 ValueA3 ValueA1 ValueB2 ValueB3") . All my element starts from word SRV. How can I separate them in array? Result: ARRAY=("ValueA1 ValueA2 ValueA3" "ValueA1 ValueB2 ValueB3")

Comment: You've written in your first post, that you already have an array. `ARRAY=("ValueA1 ValueA2 ValueA3 ValueA1 ValueB2 ValueB3")` may be an array, but contains only **one** value so far --> `ValueA1 ValueA2 ValueA3 ValueA1 ValueB2 ValueB3`
Maybe you should clarify your initial situation.
I'm sorry, but I don't get the purpose of your inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.
You talk about arrays, but you read a file. I'll put the data into arrays, in case that's what you needed...

If you need arrays, read it as an array.

```
$: cat xy.dat # used the two you had in your array that I could copy/paste
SRV WW ZSTG HSM BlackDuck RW
SRV WW ZSDB M204 BlackDuck RW

$: cat xy
#! /bin/env bash

declare -a array1=() array2=()
while read -ra row
do array1+=( "${row[*]}" ) # NOTE: using * makes one string of the row; @ would separate them
   [[ -n "${row[3]}" ]] && array2+=( "${row[3]}" )
done < "$1" # don't use capital FILE.

declare -p array1 array2 # show the contents

$: xy xy.dat
declare -a array1=([0]="SRV WW ZSTG HSM BlackDuck RW" [1]="SRV WW ZSDB M204 BlackDuck RW")
declare -a array2=([0]="HSM" [1]="M204")
```

If you don't particularly need arrays, or only need the second one, then simplify.

```
$: cat xy
#! /bin/env bash
while read -r one two three four five six
do [[ -n "$four" ]] && array2+=( "$four" )
done < "$1"
declare -p array2

$: xy xy.dat
declare -a array2=([0]="HSM" [1]="M204")
```

If you don't particularly need array2 either, just do whatever parsing you needed as you read through.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much, Could you please help me with this: My array right nowt doesn't separate. it  looks like ARRAY=("SRV WW ZSTG HSM BlackDuck RW SRV WW ZSDB M204 BlackDuck RW") . All new element starts from "SRV" word. How can I separate them in array? Result: ARRAY=("SRV WW ZSTG HSM BlackDuck RW" "SRV WW ZSDB M204 BlackDuck RW")

Comment: look at my first example. Or, `while read -r line; do array1+=("$line"); done` Certainly read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for read examples and advice, and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays for arrays examples and advice.