# How to remove a part of a Filename using bash

Tags: bash, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a some filenames that I would like to (ideally manually) rename using a bash script which is run every hour using crontab.

The Filenames are as such:

```
SeriesName v01 (Year) (Other irrelevant Data).ext
SeriesName v02 (Year) (Other irrelevant Data).ext
SeriesName v03 (Year) (Other irrelevant Data).ext
and so on
```

I would like to rename them to this :

```
SeriesName 01 (Year) (Other irrelevant Data).ext
SeriesName 02 (Year) (Other irrelevant Data).ext
SeriesName 03 (Year) (Other irrelevant Data).ext
and so on
```

The files are sometimes in subfolders
How would I do this? I know that I can use `find -type f -name '*.ext'` to find all Files that match the extension I want, but how can I remove the `v`?

Comment: Have a look at the rename cmd in bash: rename [options] <expression> <replacement> <file>... There are loads of examples online.

Comment: also could look at string manipulation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469849/how-to-split-one-string-into-multiple-strings-separated-by-at-least-one-space-in) and [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

Comment: for file in * ; do mv "$file" "${file/ v/ }"; done << will do the job at least in the current directory

Comment: @FreudianSlip I tried your script an it seems to work pretty well, but I've noticed something: when it renames, it removes the whitespace between SeriesName and 01, what can i do to add it back?

Comment: just remove the space in this : `"${file/ v/ }"` , should be like: `"${file/v/}"`  .

Comment: @User123 that seems to work, but only if there's a single `v` in the file, if any other `v` are present, only the first one will get removed

Comment: As per the sample input provided, the only logic to rename the files seems to be : removing the v from filename ...

Comment: yes, but when I do that, and the `v` is in the `SeriesName`, the `v` won't be removed later on. Only the first `v` will be removed. Can I somehow start the code looking from the end of the filename?

Comment: @User123 @FreudianSlip
I figured out how to avoid the Filename, I replaced `/v/` with `/v0/0`, not I just need to find out, wether or not I can loop this with v1 to v9