# How do I loop over a string's words in POSIX sh (or bash) in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, posix

I have been trying to find a solution
to how to loop over words in a string
but I am unable to find anything so I
decided to ask here :)

Basically, so far I tried looping over
these ways:

- One (not POSIX)

```bash
while read -r line; do
   for token in "${line[@]}"; do
        echo "* $token"
   done
done
```

- Two

```bash
while read -r line; do
   for token in $line}; do
        echo "* $token"
   done
done
```

- Three

```bash
while read -r line; do
   for token in "${line}"; do
        echo "* $token"
   done
done
```

They all fail:

- #1 doesn't split
- #2 splits but also globs
- #3 doesn't split

And I can't find a solution, any idea how
to do it?

I don't even care if it's POSIX at this point,
thanks for the answers in advance

Comment: You wouldn't expect the first to work because `line` isn't an array.

Comment: In Bash, you can use `read -a` to split into array elements without globbing, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30212526/3266847). (The two highest voted answers use unquoted expansion, which is an anti-pattern.)

Comment: @BenjaminW. whoop, sorry, how did I forget of such basic feature, very sorry for making this question