# Print string variable that stores the output of a command in Bash

Tags: bash, macos

I need to place the output of a command in Bash into a string variable.

Each value should be separated by a space. There are many options to do that but I cannot use `mapfile`or `read` options (I'm using Bash < 4 version in macOS).

This is the output of the command:

`values="$(mycommand | awk 'NR > 2 { printf "%s\n", $2 }')"`

where `mycommand` is just a cloud command that gets some values like:

`echo $values`

**mycommand output:** (which I think is a string ending with **\n** for each value)

```
55369972
75369973
85369974
95369975
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

Here I should print the values like (I need to iterate over the variable `values` so I can print each value individually).

**desired output in the foor loop**

```
value: 55369972
value: 75369973
value: 85369974
value: 95369975
```

but I'm getting this:

`value: 55369972 75369973 85369974 95369975`

```
# Getting the id field of the values
values="$(mycommand| awk 'NR > 2 { printf "%s\n", $2 }')"
# Replacing the new line with a space so I can iterate over each value
new_values="${values//$'\n'/ }"
# new_values=("${values//$'\n'/ }")
# Checking if I can print each value correctly
for i in "${new_values[@]}"
# for i in "$new_values"
do
  echo "value: ${i}"
done
```

Also, I cannot use things like

```
# shellcheck disable=xxx
values=($(echo "${values}" | tr "\n" " "))
```

As I'm getting error messages when checking the code...

Any idea what I'm doing wrong in my code?

Comment: The variable `new_values` computed as `new_values="${values//$'\n'/ }"` is a string, not an array. It makes no sense to iterate on its presumed elements.

Comment: Since we don't have access to your command `mycommand`, you could simplify your question by initializing in your sample of code the variable `values` to the string `55369972 75369973...` (with blanks or newlines as separators).

Comment: `printf "value: %i\n" $values` or `echo "$values" | sed 's/^/value: /'`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

values="$(mycommand | awk 'NR > 2 { printf "%s\n", $2 }')"
for v in $values; do
  echo value: $v
done
```

Comment: In my case it's not working since the output is a string with ('\n' at the end of each field). I tried your code but getting `value: 55369972 55369978 55369975`

Comment: can you please try adding `IFS=' '` before the for loop ?

Comment: Same output even adding `IFS=' '` before the loop. I'm using the shell `zhs` in macOS. I'm not sure if that's the issue here.

Comment: since you have the bash shebang it shouldn't matter, can you please share the actual command of "mycommand"?

Comment: The command is just a cloud command that gets some values. For example, `az xxx all-values` and the output is like the one I posted.

Comment: what happens if you just modify the awk to print the "value", the command would be:
`values="$(mycommand | awk 'NR > 2 { printf "value %s\n", $2 }')"`

then just `echo $values`

Comment: I'm getting `value value01` under `value value02` under `value value03`

Comment: isnt that what is required ?

Comment: No, it's not.  I need to place the output in a string (or a list) separated by space so later I can iterate over each value in the for loop and print the value ``value: value01` value: value02`. I can't iterate like I want with you code.

Comment: I think you need to change the way your are retrieving the data from azure. for example:
`IFS=$'\n' regions=($(az account list-locations --query "[].name" -o tsv))
for region in "${regions[@]}"; do
  echo "$region"
done`

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't paste code into the comments, I post an answer but the credits go to @akathimy above.

This works for me (solution #1):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Getting the id field of the values
values="55369972 75369973 85369974 95369975"
# 
for v in $values; do
  echo value: "$v"
done
```

and this also (solution #2):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Getting the id field of the values
values="55369972
75369973
85369974
95369975"
# 
for v in $values; do
  echo value: "$v"
done
```

**Edit**: And what about this one (solution #3)? :

```
#!/bin/bash
# Getting the id field of the values
values=("55369972
75369973
85369974
95369975")
# 
for v in ${values[@]}; do
  echo value: "$v"
done
```

This last one works for me, and perhaps also for you. Let me know.

Comment: In my case it's not working since the output is a string with ('\n' at the end of each field). I tried your code but getting value: 55369972 55369978 55369975

Comment: @Shefferdock: You mean the second version of my code above doesn't work? In my environment, it does. I see your OS is MacOS. Shall this make a difference?

Comment: the second version of your code does not cinlude '\n' at the end of each value, right? Each value in my output is ending with \n I think.

Comment: @Shefferdock: the code above (solution #2) introduces a new line into the string at the moment of the initialization. As you can see, the assignment `value="..."` splits over several lines, isn't it?

Comment: Youy are right. However, the output of my command is doing something strange as it's not working the same way than your code. Is there any way to check if the values of what I'm putting in the variable have new lines at the end of each value?

Comment: @Shefferdock: redirect the output of your command to a file (with the operator `>`) and see which chars are used at the end of the lines with some utility like `od`.

Answer (score 0):

Your step that replaces the newlines with spaces renders it as a string. If you want to split that string into a list, you should put it in brackets (based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469849/how-to-split-one-string-into-multiple-strings-separated-by-at-least-one-space-in) )

This should do what you are expecting:

```
# Getting the id field of the values
values="$(mycommand| awk 'NR > 2 { printf "%s\n", $2 }')"
# Replacing the new line with a space
new_values=("${values//$'\n'/ }")
# Checking if I can print the values correctly
for i in ${new_values}
do
  echo "value: ${i}"
done
```

where `new_values=("${values//$'\n'/ }")` is the crucial part, then you need to avoid putting it in quotes when you iterate it (or you turn it back into a string)

Comment: I'm trying your code but still getting the wrong output `value: value01 value02 value03...`. I think the output of my command is a string with '\n' at the end of the values (correct me if I'm wrong). If I print the `new_values` when I replace the `\n` with a `space` and place the values into a list I get (value01 value02 value03...) which seems correct but in the `for loop`I'm still getting `value_value01 value02 value03 ...`

Comment: I tested the code with:

values="1

2

3

5"

as a replacement for your input, and it worked. Can I check that your for loop is `for i in ${new_values}` without any quotation marks?

Comment: sorry, `values=$'1\n2\n3\n5'` even (markdown wont let me write newlines in comments)